# Why is addition assignment is much slower than assignment?

Tags: python

I'm quite new to improving python efficiency. So i've made some tests like;

Example 1:

```
num = 0
num = 2*2
# time: 13.8 ns ± 0.158 ns per loop
```

Example 2:

```
num = 0
num += 2*2
# time: 23.8 ns ± 0.232 ns per loop
```

I am wondering why using addition assignment is much slower, is it because it has addition?

Comment: How are you measuring these, for one? Also, the context in which these are executed may drastically affect execution speed – eg. local variables are faster than globals.

Comment: The first one can basically be done by the parser at parse time, whereas the second actually needs to do runtime calculations…?! This really depends on the compiler and what optimisations it might throw at it. Try to `dis` the code to see what it'll do…

Comment: @deceze CPython does peephole-optimize `2*2` to a `LOAD_CONST 4`, but just `dis`ing doesn't necessarily help since global name lookups/writes are slower than locals, and we don't know what OP is doing exactly.

Answer (score 3):

It will become clearer if you use the dis module and wrap everything in a function:

```
    import dis
    def change_link():
        num = 0
        num = 2*2
    def add():
        num = 0 
        num += 2*2

    dis.dis(change_link)
    dis.dis(add)
```

You will see that change_link() function has fewer steps:

```
0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
2 STORE_FAST               0 (num)
4 LOAD_CONST               2 (4)
6 STORE_FAST               0 (num)
8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
10 RETURN_VALUE
```

instead of add() function:

```
0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
2 STORE_FAST               0 (num)
4 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
6 LOAD_CONST               2 (4)
8 INPLACE_ADD
10 STORE_FAST               0 (num)
12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Simply put, there is much easier to change link to value, than correct (ex. add or multiply) the value.

Answer (score 2):

> is it because it has addition?

Yes, addition assignment requires the value to be read from memory before writing the new value, whereas a simple assignment does not require this reading step and can just write the value, making it faster.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in one case you have 2 operations: 1 multiplication `2*2`
(assuming that it is not already done at parse time. I don't really know the internal of the interpreter. It probably is), and 1 assignment `num=4`.

In the other 3: 1 multiplication `2*2`, 1 addition `num+4`, and one assignment `num=4`

Note that the ratio is certainly less than 3/2 in time. Because anyway, those are probably not the heaviest part of the computation.  Accessing memory for example takes longer that an addition. Plus, there is the measurement time. If you measure

```py
for i in range(100000000):
   x=2*2
```

a good part of what you'll measure is the for loop.

So, there is a big common part in timings. And only a small part is about the difference between the 2 operations. The 3/2 (more realisticly 2/1, since I am pretty sure, without knowing anything about it, that python replace 2*2 by 4 at parsing time. Even my own simple pedagogical interpreters do so. That's a basic feature, and python interpreters are generally not basic), so that 3/2 or 2/1 ratio applies only on a fraction of the computation time.

But, well, it is quite normal that `x+=2*2` is more expansive than `x=2*2`, even if only slightly so.

Comment: You forgot to mention the load (since `num` isn't a constant). And you shouln't measure timing this way. The `timeit` module is designed to that for you, to measure the timing without the loop overhead.

Comment: I know about timeit. And obviously so does the OP. But the question, and my answer is not about how to measure that "num+=2*2" is slower than "num=2*2", but about **why** it is